# UITextView KeyboardAppearance property to set UIKeyboardAppearanceDark

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uiappearance

I simply want the keyboard of UITextView to appear in dark mode. However UItextView doesn't have such a property.

Normally for UITextField you can use the following to change the keyboards across the app:

`[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];`

However when I try the following, app crashes:

`[[UITextView appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceDark];`

So, my question is simple, is there a way to change keyboard appearance when I use UITextView? I hope and want to believe that Apple didn't forget to add such a feature to UITextView.

Comment: Is this in your delegate?

Comment: Just in case this helps. I also ran into this problem. I was running this code in my AppDelegate just like OP and it would result in a fun error of "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'". I cannot tell you how many places I looked before finally just going line by line in my git diff to find out what changed. This type of crash sucks!

Answer (score 16):

There are 2 simple ways to do this

1. Programmatically

   ```
   self.textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
   ```
2. Storyboard or nib file
   [image]

Comment: Too bad you have to do this for every textview you have in the app