# App crashes when changing text view keyboard appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I want to change text view keyboard appearance for my app using this

```
UITextView.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

However, my app crashed with this error

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The weird thing is that I use the same method for UITextfield

```
 UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

and it works

Can anyone please explain the reason behind this? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView KeyboardAppearance property to set UIKeyboardAppearanceDark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21503906/uitextview-keyboardappearance-property-to-set-uikeyboardappearancedark)

Comment: I think that provides you with a workaround but doesn't explain the crash.

Answer (score 0):

is it running on Xcode 10 GM?
Then, try this:
remove '/usr/lib/libstdc++abi.dylib' from the 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'.